# Prevent HTC Vive from disabling VR due to low performance

Tags: vive, steam-vr

I was having issues with some games not loading in VR mode even though SteamVR showed all green. I ended up enabling developer notifications, and saw that I would get a performance warning whenever I opened a game. What I think is happening is that the Vive is shutting off VR as soon as these games run because it detects performance issues. What's really happening is that these games that perform splendidly are using up a bunch of resources in an instant when they first boot up, and I believe the Vive just assumes it will always use that many resources and never looks back.

Is there any way to disable the Vive's tendency to kick players out into Home whenever it detects an "issue" (which can lead to flickering of the Home/games in some cases)?

Edit: Yeah, that's definitely what's happening. When assets are being loaded in at the beginning, there are some spikes in performance, but after they've been loaded in performance smooths out:
[image]